# Find selected/focused page of current word document (Word, C#)

Tags: c#, ms-word

i am looking for a way to determine the page (as int) where the current focus is. In the Method

```
document.ExportAsFixedFormat(outputpath, 
                             Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, 
                             false, 
                             Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen,
                           **Word.WdExportRange.wdExportCurrentPage**, 
                             0, 0, Word.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, 
                             true, false, 
                             Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, 
                             false, false, false,ref missing);
```

is a parameter for that. But i want to save as Worddocument. In the Method

```
document.SaveAs2(outputpath, 
                 missing, missing, missing, 
                 missing, missing, missing, 
                 missing, missing, missing, 
                 missing, missing, missing, 
                 missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

is no such a parameter.

Anyone got an idea how i can save the document with the current focus ?

Comment: sorry, didnt know. i changed it.

Comment: no problem, that's a common mistake. It's hard to find proper tags sometimes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "focus" you mean "the page where the insertion point is", the C# based on the following VBA sample may be enough:

```
activedocument.Bookmarks("\page").range.exportfragment "c:\a\frag1.docx",wdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
```

(Edit: The OP provided the following C#:

```
worddocument.Bookmarks[@"\Page"].Range.ExportFragment(exportPath, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
```

)

Comment: OK, thanks for the update - I have included your code in my post so we can both delete these comments...